# GenericDAO inheritance from interface

Tags: java, generics, interface, dao

I have an abstract DAO:

```
public abstract class AbstractJpaDAO<T extends Serializable> implements I_AbstractJpaDAO<T> {

private Class<T> clazz;

@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager entityManager;

public final void setClazz(final Class<T> clazzToSet) {
    this.clazz = clazzToSet;
}

@Override
public T findOne(final long id) {
    return entityManager.find(clazz, id);
}

@Override
public List<T> findAll() {
    return entityManager.createQuery("from " + clazz.getName()).getResultList();
}

@Override
public void create(final T entity) {
    entityManager.persist(entity);
}

@Override
public T update(final T entity) {
    return entityManager.merge(entity);
}

@Override
public void delete(final T entity) {
    entityManager.remove(entity);
}

@Override
public void deleteById(final long entityId) {
    final T entity = findOne(entityId);
    delete(entity);
}
 }
```

I then extend this DAO in each DAO implementation (code not included) but header something like:

```
 public class UserDAOImpl extends AbstractJpaDAO <User> implements UserDAO {
 .....
```

With each entity, I work with a base interface type, for this example,let's call it UserDAO, and have an associated implementation, let's call it, UserDAOIMPL. To avoid having to define the same methods each Interface to each DAO. As in this longwinded example, i.e :

```
 public interface UserDAO {
  User findOne(long id);
  List<User> findAll();
  void create(User user);
  User update(User user);
  void delete(User user);
  void deleteById(long userID);
  User findUserByUserName(String name);
  EntityManager returnEntityManager();
  }
```

I would like to instead create a base interface, that all DAOs can extend.

```
 public interface I_AbstractJpaDAO<T> {
 .....
 }
```

and then use this in each DAO interface.

```
 public interface userDAO extends I_AbstractJpaDAO<T> { .....
```

However, I'm getting problems with "both methods have erasure, but neither overrides the other". Something to do with the Serialization thing I suspect. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that, your base interface and abstract interface have the methods with the same signature and different return type.

Try this:

```
public interface userDAO extends I_AbstractJpaDAO<User> { .....
```